# Will I be allowed to enter Dubai with 7 days left on my visa?

Tags: visas, dubai

I have a 60-day tourist visa which expires on 9 July, 2015. I want to travel there on the 4th of July. Will I be allowed to enter and how many days can I spend there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will. Tourist visas are valid for the whole period specified.  You don't have to enter on the first day of the visa.

However, they may ask for evidence of your accommodation and / or exit flight/bus.  Have this ready to hand.  Other than that, there's no reason you shouldn't be permitted in.